# Execute bash command inside awk and print command output

Tags: awk, system, getline

Given a file `test.txt` with the following contents:

```
ABC DEF GATTAG GHK
ABC DEF GGCGTC GHK 
ABC DEF AATTCC GHK
```

the 3rd column needs to be modified, so that the string is reverse complement. Part of it can be done with a bash command:

`cat test.txt | cut -f3 | rev | tr ATGC TACG`

```
CTAATC
GACGCC
GGAATT
```

**How can this be implemented with `awk`?** *(there is a bigger awk script for processing of files, which this function will be added to.)*

One possible way this might be done is by executing `rev | tr ATGC TACG` inside of `awk`, similar to:

```
awk '{newVar=system("rev | tr ATGC TACG"$3); print $1 $2 newVar $4}' test.txt
```

However, this and various similar versions do not work. Can someone point out what is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the string reversal and translation in awk itself:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
        old="ATGC"
        new="TACG"
        for (i=1;i<=length(old);i++) {
            tr[substr(old,i,1)] = substr(new,i,1)
        }
    }
    {
        newVar=""
        for (i=1;i<=length($3);i++) {
            char = substr($3,i,1)
            newVar = (char in tr ? tr[char] : char) newVar
        }
        print $1, $2, newVar, $4
    }
' file
ABC DEF CTAATC GHK
ABC DEF GACGCC GHK
ABC DEF GGAATT GHK
```

If you really feel a burning need to call an external tool from awk and read the result back that'd be:

```
$ awk '
    {
        cmd="echo \047" $3 "\047 | rev | tr \047ATGC\047 \047TACG\047"
        newVar=((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "failed")
        close(cmd)
        print $1, $2, newVar, $4
    }
' file
ABC DEF CTAATC GHK
ABC DEF GACGCC GHK
ABC DEF GGAATT GHK
```

but you should expect a significant performance hit from doing that and see also the getline caveats: http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: fyi: http://awk.freeshell.org/ is not working, found a snapshot on https://web.archive.org/web/20170524214527/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Comment: Yeah I noticed it went away about a month ago. I had started using that reference after awk.info went away. Maybe it's best referenced in the google groups view of comp.lang.awk usenet group where I actually posted it: https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.lang.awk/2TA76BVODz4/Q9TkehK_tWYJ

Comment: suggestion: may be create a github repo or gist or similar, or community wiki here..

Comment: Yeah, Ive thought about it. I actually had something on freeservers at one time with a bunch of awk scripting recipes but that vanished overnight and I didn't pursue it. Then it was on awk.info and that vanished, and now awk.freeshell.org has vanished too. Life's too short...

Answer (score 1):

if `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -lane '$F[2]=~tr/ATGC/TACG/; $F[2]=reverse $F[2]; print "@F"' test.txt 
ABC DEF CTAATC GHK
ABC DEF GACGCC GHK
ABC DEF GGAATT GHK
```

- `-a` option would split the line on whitespaces and save to `@F` array

  - See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches for other options
  - Use `perl -i -lane` for inplace editing
- `$F[2]=~tr/ATGC/TACG/` use `tr` only for 3rd column
- `$F[2]=reverse $F[2]` reverse the string for 3rd column
- `print "@F"` print the modified array with space as separator

Can also be written as

```
perl -lane '$F[2]=reverse $F[2]=~tr/ATGC/TACG/r; print "@F"' test.txt
```

or using Perl code in replacement section

```
perl -pe 's/^(\H+\h+){2}\K\H+/reverse $&=~tr|ATGC|TACG|r/e' test.txt
```